# Developing flash application with facebook

Tags: facebook, air, adobe

I am developing an application in which I want to create the flash button,textfield,label,So for that purpose which tools i require.I have downloaded and installed the Adobe on my system
which has following configuration

- Intel Core i3 processor
- Windows 7 home
- 64-bit operating System

Adobe AIR installed successfully but i don't do how to use the Adobe AIR so please let me know how to use Adobe AIR and also tell me what are the other tools required?
Please guide me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add flash button, textfield etc. then you have to download and install flash professional CS5, because this IDE is necessary to create any of the flash related stuff.

you have installed adobe AIR, thats good but only AIR is not enough, you have to make SWF file through CS5 to get the things.

Comment: Thanks Vipul for your answer

Comment: Ok I am working on the prototyping of the project in which VB.Net User Interface is there which contains buttons,textfields and the use case that the signals from RFID device coming that will be shown by the UI,So please le me know how to make the swf file of the UI

Comment: Are you trying to say that all of your UI is from VB.NET, because i m not getting your "use case that the signals from RFID device coming that will be shown by the UI" part.

Comment: Yes My All UI is from VB.Net and I want to use Flash equivalent control for the VB.net control So please let me know

Comment: hello Vipul when I am trying to install Adobe Flash professional cs6 on my windows 7 64-bit machine it cannot get install on the machine but it shos the error that "A restart is pending bootstrapper error" Then I restart my machine and trying to install the software again but it gets failed So i have googling on this problem then i get that the issue can be resolve by deleting Inprogress registray key but I don't know how to delete In progress registry key please let me know Thanks in Advance

Comment: you can find the registry key in registry editor, open RUN, by pressing windows + R, type "regedit", it will open editor whrer in software section you can find that inprogress key.

one more thing i want to mention that you are trying to install flash CS6 on your 64 bit machine, please confirm that your software is for 64 bit machine, otherwise it will not install on your machine.